# Error: Cannot read property 'length' of null when create new Component in AngularCLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-routing

In angular 4 I use

ng g c componentname

But It shows error that is:

"Error: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Cannot read property 'length' of null".

So how can I solved above problem?

Thank you so much and best regard. Please see attachment for more detail
[image]

Comment: It would be better if you share your code, where you are getting error

Comment: I think my error come from package.json. It's doesn't related on my source code, It just related on the version of package I installed on my local. But I don't know why and I'm finding what is the problem. Thank you for your comment @Neeraj Rathod.

Comment: try after clearing cache clean `npm cache clean -f` and re run your command for creating component

Comment: I'd say - first make versions of global and local @angular/cli match and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @PardeepJain, It's not resolved my problem, Thank you for your comment. I'll try another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I found the way to resolved above problem, add --skip-import=true after the ng generate component statement.

You can use the argument --skip-import to skip adding it to module.